# Cannot reach website due to bad DNS (even while using curl and clearing all caches)

Tags: ubuntu, dns

I have a website running for 2 years now. A week ago, I changed the DNS records for this website. On all other devices other than *this* laptop, the website can be accessed normally. On this laptop, a route to that domain cannot be found or any of its subdomains. I am running Ubuntu 15.10 LTS.

I have tried using Google Chrome, Firefox, Curl.

Chrome says:
`server DNS address could not be found. ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Firefox keeps on connecting forever.

Curl says on `curl -I mywebsite.com`:
`curl: (6) Could not resolve host:`

Tracepath says on `tracepath mywebsite.com`: `gethostbyname2: Unknown host`

Nslookup:

```
nslookup mywebsite.com
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find mywebsite.com: No answer
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I have run all of these commands to clear DNS cache:
`sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean restart` `sudo /etc/init.d/networking force-reload` `sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart` `sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart`.

My `/etc/hosts/` doesn't contain the domain name or any sub-domains.
`/etc/dnsmasq.conf` only contains one line for binding `local` to `127.0.0.1`. The laptop has been restarted multiple times. I have tried different Wifi connections. It just does not work. `dnsmasq` has the caching-timeout of 0 so it doesn't cache DNS lookups.

Which demon has devoured my DNS lookup table?

Comment: OK, I know your trying to keep your information private, but you haven't given us the output of /etc/resolv.conf or nslookup... it sounds like the problem is external... you could verify for certain by trying `nslookup website.com` which would use your normal DSN service and `nslookup website.com 8.8.8.8` which would force it to Google's DNS service.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Note: Using my phone on this same WiFi connection, I can connect to the website. Surely the problem is internal.

Comment: Using Google's DNS service it works fine.

Comment: As can be seen from resolv.conf you might be using internal DNS-server. How long does this problem persist? Can you resolve other websites?

Comment: All other websites are working fine. Just this website and its subdomains.

Comment: If you use bind, try `rndc flush` Then, restart your router.

Comment: Also, what is the output of `nslookup your_site your_router`.

Comment: Oh man you are a genius. I wonder how is it working on my phone (My Nexus 5 forces using another DNS?) and not on my laptop. It turns out it is the router. I'll try to clear the DNS cache of the router. Thanks

Comment: Turns out the ISP's DNS provider cannot find it also, but Google's can. Too bad, I must have to wait.